# How to install Skype on 16.04.1?

Tags: 16.04, skype

I don't know how to install Skype on Ubuntu 16.04.1. It was all okay until I updated my Ubuntu and now I can't install Skype.

Comment: Add Canonical Partner repo and install by `sudo apt install skype`.

Comment: Try the skype alpha instead of the ubuntu old school skype

Answer (score 2):

You can get Skype 4.3 on 16.04 by enabling the Partners repository, as others have said. However, it isn't really worth it. Skype will open, but you won't be able to do a lot of things, [including group calls](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/02/skype-for-linux-group-calls-need-to-update-issue) (this is a problem with all Linux distros). You may or may not also have dependency issues, as these have been reported on 16.04.

Instead of Skype 4.3, you should get the [Skype for Linux Alpha app](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Alpha-and-calling-on-Chrome-amp-Chromebooks/td-p/4434299) (download the DEB). It's still in alpha, as the name suggests, but it currently has all the features of Skype Web.

If you want to fully use Skype on Ubuntu 16.04, you'll need the Alpha version.

Comment: @blaskszminki Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If the answer solved your problem, rather than thanking in a comment please use the arrow to upvote the answer and tick the checkmark in order to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Just installed Skype 4.3 on 16.04 with `sudo apt install skype`. Wouldn't call it a "significant effort", and it works fine, so I have to question the statement in your answer.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I've seen a lot of reports that Skype causes a dependency hell in 16.04. I've also seen articles saying that Skype for Linux has issues with group chats, group calls and some other things, since MS stopped supporting the older protocols.

Comment: I have also seen reported dependency issues - not only on 16.04, btw. My belief is that they don't apply to fresh installs, though. As regards group chats, it's a known limitation. It would be good IMO if you modified your answer a bit.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I'll remove the difficulty remark, but the call issue seems credible http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/02/skype-for-linux-group-calls-need-to-update-issue

Comment: Yep, the call issue is worth mentioning (but it has nothing to do with  16.04).

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson edited.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the Canonical Partners in Software & Updates -> Other Software first. Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

In a Terminal. Or like Zacharee mentioned, you can download the alpha version of Skype.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Franz](http://meetfranz.com/). Franz is a free messaging app.

1. Download it from here: [Download Franz](http://meetfranz.com/#download_all) e.g. the 64bit Linux version
2. Extract it: `cd /tmp; mkdir Franz; tar xvfz Franz-linux-x64-3.1.1.tgz -C Franz`
3. Place it: `sudo cp -a Franz /opt/Franz; sudo ln -s /opt/Franz/Franz /usr/local/bin/.`
4. Run it: Press `ALT+F2` and type: `Franz`
5. Add **Skype** Service using your login and password

Comment: (Almost) link only answers are not considered good. You could [edit] your answer to add some more about Franz, maybe how to install, how to set up and some screenshots?